# Changes to uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc in Drupal 6.x and Ubercart 2.x Have No Effect

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I want to simply move the Qty column to the right so it is next to the Price column on the cart/checkout page. I tried doing this with `hook_alter_form`. I tried making a custom module, doing it in `template.php`, and changing `uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc` directly but any changes I make do not take effect.

I have cleared my caches, run cron, everything... and it's just not working.

I have tried disabling modules and it has no effect either. What could be preventing changes made directly in the core file from taking effect. If I delete 50 lines of random code, it crashes the site, so it seems to be loading directly from `uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc`, but if I make changes, even making `t('Subtotal')` say `t('Subtotalchanged')`, it doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have any clue what's going on?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit tired when I wrote this. Hook_form_alter doesn't really have anything to do with this.

The main thing is that I've tried changing theme_cart_review_table and theme_uc_checkout_pane_cart_review in my template.php, as well as directly in uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc and the changes won't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the UC Discounts (Alternative) module overrides the uc_checkout_pane_cart_review within the module. This was confusing because my understanding is that theme overrides should take precedence over modules, but that wasn't the case.

I'm submitting a bug report to them to find out what is going on, but that is what was keeping me from making changes.